# Error Code: 1136 Column count doesn't match value SQL procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Error:

```
call ZThinQ.ZThinQ_ApplianceId_Create(@pApplianceId, '', 'name', 'code', 'xyz', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 0.031 sec

before 'name' i don't know how this '' extra added.
Here is a code of my procedures

```
 OUT pApplianceId BIGINT,
        IN pApplianceName VARCHAR(128),
        IN pApplianceCategoryCode VARCHAR(32),
        IN pDescription VARCHAR(1024),
        IN pPinNumber INT,
        IN pIsConfigured BIT(1),
        IN pIsSwitchedOn BIT(1),
        IN pDeviceId BIGINT(20),
        IN pPlaceId BIGINT(20),
        IN pStatus BIT(1),
        IN pIsDeleted BIT(1),
        IN pIsArchived BIT(1),
        IN pCreatedBy BIGINT(20),
        IN pModifiedBy BIGINT(20),
        IN pCompanyId BIGINT(20),
        IN pOwnerCompanyId BIGINT(20)

        )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `ZThinQ_Appliance`
        (
            `ApplianceName`,
            `ApplianceCategoryCode`,
            `Description`,
            `PinNumber`,
            `IsConfigured`,
            `IsSwitchedOn`,
            `DeviceId_FK`,
            `PlaceId_FK`,
            `CompanyId_FK`,
            `OwnerCompanyId_FK`,
            `Status`,
            `IsDeleted`,
            `IsArchived`,
            `CreatedDate`,
            `ModifiedDate`,
            `ModifiedBy_FK`,
            `CreatedBy_FK`
        )
        VALUES
        (
            pApplianceName,
            pApplianceCategoryCode,
            pDescription,
            pPinNumber,
            pIsConfigured,
            pIsSwitchedOn,
            pDeviceId,
            pPlaceId,
            pStatus,
            pCompanyId,
            pIsDeleted,
            pIsArchived,
            pOwnerCompanyId,
            pCompanyId,
            UTC_TIMESTAMP(),
            UTC_TIMESTAMP(),
            pCreatedBy,
            pModifiedBy


        );

        SET pApplianceId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: mysql  @jarlh is using